# Rendering <option value="foo" selected> on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

React v0.12/v0.13: I’m having an issue with a `<select>` element that I’d like to have rendered both on the server and in the client (isomorphic). Here’s an example which currently recreates the issue:

```
const React = require("react");

const SelectedDebug = React.createClass({
  displayName: "SelectedDebug",

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value="C">
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = SelectedDebug;
```

The `selected` attribute isn’t rendered on the server, but works fine in the browser.

I've also tried setting the `defaultValue` prop on the `<select>` element, which doesn't seem to make a difference. It *does* work when I use `<option value="C" selected>`, however, that throws a warning in the console telling me to use either the `value` or `defaultValue` prop.

The documentation also describes the desired behavior: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value

This code is running in Node v0.12 using [babel-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core) for transpiling.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

**Update:** This is a bug in React. See my comment/link below.

Comment: Apparently, this is a known bug: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3594. (I'm not going to delete this, as it might help someone who's googling this bug, and since Facebook keeps closing the issue at GitHub.)

Comment: Looks like the bug *just* got fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3595

Comment: Wow, that was quick :-D Thanks for letting me know, @insin.

Comment: @insin - could you add an answer, people that see this question in the list might think that there is no solution yet to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1398) which has been [fixed in master](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3595), so will presumably be fixed with the release of React 0.14.